# convert a sparse matrix to dense and get the full eigenvalues

Tags: python, c++, matrix

recently I'm working on a problem which requires
diagonalizing a huge hermitian matrix to get all the eigenvalues.
Currently I'm using Mathematica to do the job.

However it is not applicable due to the limitation of memory 
when the matrix size approaches (2^15,2^15), where the diagonalization costs approximately 32 GBs memory.

I've tried using python by importing the matrix from mathematica,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import mmread
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

#importing sparse matrix to save space
h = mmread("h.mtx")
h = csc_matrix(h)
#diagonlizing the dense one
ev = np.linalg.eigvalsh(h.todense())
```

It works but unfortunately an order of magnitude slower than Mathematica.

So, is there any other possible solutions, say, C++?

I know nothing about C++ so I guess the simplest way may be importing the 
matrix to C++ and diagonalizing.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't know about Mathematica, and I might be wrong, but I doubt it does the transformation to a dense matrix to then get the eigenvalues. You should, most likely, use the `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` method as documented here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel i believe he wants the full eigenvalues. Sparse methods usually target a subset of eigenvalues(k parameter in `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`)

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking. Can you do this in C++? Yes sure. You need to know which format your matrix is in and then find/write a input library for this. They you can pass it to Eigen(easier) or Lapack(standard) to diagonalize. Intel has this nice decision tree for lapack: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-symmetric-eigenvalue-problems-lapack-computational-routines

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Yes I need the full eigenvalues so the dense matrix is a must.

Comment: @Stein I don't know C++ so I'm looking for the solution as you described, in a more detailed, newbie-friendly manner.

Comment: @empyriumz what format are you using? MatrixMarket? Then I'd use this library to read the file: http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/mmio-c.html 
Then you need to create a Eigen( http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page ) matrix of the right size where you set all the elements.
Finally you calculate the eigenvalues using https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html
Eigen has a very good documentation. You'll have to browse this. A full intro to C++ would be out of scope for a question on stackoverflow

Comment: @Stein I'm using "*.mtx" format. Is this readable for c++? Thank you for your useful instruction!

Comment: I believe this is matrix market. You can find an explanation here: http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html the also provide a library to read it. Are you sure you need the FULL eigenvalue spectrum? Can you rewrite you problem a a linear system? A full matrix decomposition of this size takes quite some time. Sparse methods which can access only certain pars of the spectrum are much quicker.

Comment: You should also check which parts of you codes takes this much time in matlab/python. For this step `ev = np.linalg.eigvalsh(h.todense())` MATLab, Python and Eigen all use a Lapack routine. So if this step takes 95% of the time(probably will) C won't help. Make sure Python uses a parallel version of Lapack and that you use the hermitian version if possible.

Comment: @Stein The benchmark shows the python is not good at handling hermitian matrices regarding to get the full spectrum, which is indeed what I want. What confuses me is it is an order of magnitude slower than Mathematica.

Comment: Can you run htop(or taskmanager under windows) to see if Mathematica & Python are using all the cores(minus hyper threading)? Are you using a dense or a sparse matrix in Mathematica?

Comment: It seems Mathematica does either LAPACK(which numpy does) or Arnoldi(which scipy offers) https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/4.4.html. Are you sure that Mathematica doesn't set the Arnoldi basis automatically smaller than N? Does Mathematic give you N Eigenvalues? See if this library would do as you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558215/finding-eigenvalues-of-huge-and-very-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running some preliminary test using this matrix:

http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/NEP/h2plus/qc2534.html

I determined that the conversion to dense does not take up much of the time. The eigenvalue calculation does.

Numpy uses highly-optimized Lapack routines to calculate. These are the same you'd use in C++. Therefore C++ won't give you much of a speedup. If you want a speedup use the sparseness as a property, go to a better computer or switch to a distributed matrix storage(lot's of labor here).

P.S: if you do this for a university project you might want to look around if your university has a cluster of some sort. A cluster node typically has lots of memory. If not, check amazons AWS EC2 or googles compute engine for instances with lot's of ram.

Edit:

Here Wolfram says what Mathematica does behind the scenes: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraAppendix.html#83486633

Arpack is a (arnoldi)subspace solver, giving you only the highest or lowest k-eigenvalues, ATLAS is just a Lapack implementation and the rest seems to be for solving linear systems.

All methods giving you the full eigenspectrum will require the matrix decomposition of a NxN matrix. If you only want k vectors there are methods which reduce it to a decomposition of a k x k-matrix.

There are modern alternatives to Arpack(http://slepc.upv.es/ or the one that comes with MKL), but they all give you a subspace.

Comment: I have access to HPC cluster with no Mathematica installed, so I have to use python which takes about 10 hours to perform one diagonalization.

Comment: 10 hours does not sound horribly wrong. I am doing 5000x5000 in ~ 5 min. 5 min * (32000/5000)^3 ~ 21 hours (on my hardware). So you seem to be in the right ballpark. Are you sure that Mathematica isn't using a subspace method without you noticing it? If you have multiple nodes scalapack might help, but there you need to do more programming.

Comment: Mathematica will automatically convert a sparse matrix to dense if you want to get the full spectrum. I'll follow your advice to seek for some scalable method.

Answer (score 0):

c++ won't help much.
In python you can delegate easily to C++ and a lot of scipy routines will do just that (for performance). I also expect that if you only time the eigen value line you will get similar performance to Matematica and the difference in performance comes from reading the data.

The best solution is to look for a more appropriate algorithm, maybe something that operates on the sparse matrix directly, or decompose the original into smaller matrices and combine them.

To make the original solution more tractable you could try increasing the amount of swap space. In linux it's a dedicated partition, in windows it's a setting. This should allow Matematica/python to use more memory, but it's going to be much slower due to memory trashing. Get an SSD to speed this setup up, but note that it's going to be destroyed faster due to often writes. Or even better buy more RAM.

Comment: My own benchmark indicates python is an order of magnitude slower than Mathematica in getting the full eigenvalues, which really confuses me.